# How do I determine in a shell script if a FTP host is up?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I need help writing a for loop to work with ftp. It needs to get its input from a text file of addresses. The scipt does not need to fully connect, just show if host is up or not. what I got so far:

```
while read p; do
  cat $p
done < /media/C2AF-FE98/ftpsites/list6.txt
```

I know that there has to be a right way to write this.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to elaborate on what exactly you mean by determining whether "the host is up or not"? (What qualifies as "the host is up"?) Also, can you give us an example entry or two from that `list6.txt` file?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you don't need to connect it looks like you need scan if the port is open. Then use a port scanner like [**nmap**](http://nmap.org/):

```
nmap  -iL /media/C2AF-FE98/ftpsites/list6.txt  -p 21
```

Explanation of the parameters taken from the [options summary](http://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html):

> `-iL <inputfilename>`: Input from list of hosts/networks
>   `-p <port ranges>`: Only scan specified ports

Comment: nmap will show port 21 open on every host in my list,  but not every host will have an ftp server running.  Thats why I need to use ftp command to check if the server is up by grabbing the welcome message.

Comment: If the FTP server is RUNNING then the port WILL appear as OPEN. It doesn't mean that it is running in a healthy status, but for sure running at least. Please specify better your requirements.

Comment: For example: 37.200.60.119 is up and running.  24.1.222.50 is not.  Both are on my list and both have port 21 open.  I really need to grab the banner and know if the ftp server is accessible.

Comment: @user3701007 You really should edit your original question to include additional information relevant to answering the question. Comments on answers should be used only for requests specific to that answer.

Comment: Please edit question and say that you want to check for ftp welcome message. Also none of those 2 IP have port 21 open from here.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use the ping command for this application:

```
for url in `cat /media/C2AF-FE98/ftpsites/list6.txt`
do
  ping -q -c1 $url || die "$url host is down."
done
```

This can be unuseful if the host filters the echo request. The nmap solution posted by @LatinSuD is more efficient.